# useQuery with useEffect for simple search

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have a pretty complicated component and now I am trying to implement a search where the user can type and it filters the results.

```
// query

  const GET_ACCOUNTS = gql`
  query accounts{
    accounts{
      id
      name
      status
      company{
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

```
// get query

  const { loading } = useQuery(GET_ACCOUNTS, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    skip: userType !== 'OS_ADMIN',
    onCompleted: setSearchResults
  });
```

```
// example of query result (more than 1)

{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "id": "5deed7df947204960f286010",
      "name": "Acme Test Account",
      "status": "active",
      "company": {
        "id": "5de84532ce5373afe23a05c8",
        "name": "Acme Inc.",
        "__typename": "Company"
      },
      "__typename": "Account"
    },
  ]
}
```

```
// states

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
```

```
// code to render

        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="seach">Search for accounts</InputLabel>
          <Input
            id="search"
            aria-describedby="Search for accounts"
            startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start"><SearchIcon /></InputAdornment>}
            value={searchTerm}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </FormControl>
{searchResults && searchResults.accounts &&
          searchResults.accounts.map(c => {
            return (
              <>
                <ListItem
                  dense
                  button
                  className={classnames({ [classes.selectedAccountContext]: c.id === accountContextId })}
                  key={c.id}
                  onClick={() => accountClicked(c.id)}
                >
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={c.name}
                    secondary={
                      <>
                        <span>{c.company.name}</span>
                        <span className="d-flex align-items-center top-margin-tiny">
                          <Badge
                            color={c.status === 'active' ? "success" : "danger"}
                            style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}
                          >
                            {c.status.replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase())}
                          </Badge>
                          <span className='ml-auto'>
                            <SvgIcon><path d={mdiMapMarkerRadius} /></SvgIcon>
                            <SMARTCompanyIcon />
                          </span>
                        </span>
                      </>
                    }
                  />
                </ListItem>
              </>
            )
          })
        }
```

```
// useEffect

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm) {
      const results = searchResults.accounts.filter((c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)))
      setSearchResults(results)
    }
  }, [searchTerm])
```

The issue is when I start typing in my search field, I am looking at my `searchResults` and it gets filtered when I type in one character, but when I type the next one it breaks.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

Also it does not render on the view even when I have typed one letter.

Comment: Can you give the initial value of `searchResults` from the get query?

Comment: @RieljunLiguid just added an example, but there are more than one maybe 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data, the initial value of `searchResults` is a dictionary with `accounts` key.  But when you update it in the `useEffect` part, it changes to a list:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm) {
      const results = searchResults.accounts.filter((c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)))

      // This changes the value of searchResults to an array
      setSearchResults(results)
    }
}, [searchTerm])
```

When the `setSearchResults` was called inside the `useEffect`, the value of `searchResults` changes from an object to an array:

from this:

searchResults = {
    accounts: [
       ...
    ]
}

to this:

searchResults = [
    ...
]

That is why it raises `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` after the first search since there is no `accounts` key anymore.

To fix this, you need to be consistent in the data type of your `searchResults`, it would be better to make it as a List in the first place.  You can do this in the `onCompleted` part:

```
const { loading } = useQuery(GET_ACCOUNTS, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    skip: userType !== 'OS_ADMIN',
    onCompleted: (data) => setSearchResults(data.accounts || [])
});
```

Notice that we set `searchResults` to the `accounts` value. After that, you also need the way on how you access `searchResults`

```
{searchResults &&
  searchResults.map(c => {
    return (
        ...renderhere
    )
  })
}
```

And your `useEffect` will be like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm) {
        const results = searchResults.filter((c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)))
        setSearchResults(results)
    }
}, [searchTerm])
```

**TIP:**

You may want to rename your `searchResults` into `accounts` to make it clearer.  Take note also that after the first search, your options will become limited to the previous search result, so you may also want to store all of the accounts in a different variable:

```
const [allAccounts, setAllAccounts] = useState([])
const [searchedAccounts, setSearchedAccounts] = useState([])

// useQuery
const { loading } = useQuery(GET_ACCOUNTS, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    skip: userType !== 'OS_ADMIN',
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setAllAccounts(data.accounts || [])
      setSearchedAccounts(data.accounts || [])
    }
});


// useEffect
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm) {
        // Notice we always search from allAccounts
        const results = allAccounts.filter((c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)))
        setSearchedAccounts(results)
    }
}, [searchTerm])
```

Comment: Thanks so when I render the output, I would do something like:

`{searchedAccounts.map(() => { return <div>})}`

And if that is the case, how do I make it so that it maps against the `allAccounts` if there is nothing in the `searchedAccounts`? Meaning I want to pull the full list of accounts after my query has ran but then start filtering it when there are search terms being entered by each letter to filter, and then show those. And if there is nothing in the search terms then show all. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If that is the case, you can just set the value of `searchedAccounts` from `allAccounts`, something like this: `setSearchedAccounts(allAccounts)`

Comment: Okay so I am going with your recommendation from the tip and have the setup like that. So do I need to modify the `useEffect` to do this? In my render I am using `searchedAccounts &&
          searchedAccounts.map`

Comment: I tried adding another `useEffect` this but it does not change the rendered view:

`useEffect(() => {
    if (searchedAccounts) {
      setSearchedAccounts(searchedAccounts)
    }
  }, [searchedAccounts])`

Comment: can you try including `allAccounts` in the useEffect paramater like `[searchTerm, allAccounts]`?

Comment: so including `allAccounts` did not work but adding `searchedAccounts` did work! Thank you very much for your help!